# How to derive this "converter" in Scala in compile time?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, type-level-computation

We have an API that receives client queries in JSON format and executes them against `as: Seq[A]` of `case class A(x: Int, y: Int)`. For example, query `{x : 0}` works as `as.filter(_.x == 0)`, `{ "and" : {x = 0, y = 1} }` works as `as.filter(a => a.x == 0 && a.y == 1)`, etc.

The problem is that `case class A` is changing and it breaks the queries.
For example, now I need to execute query `{ "and" : {x = 0, y = 1} }` against `Seq[A1]` of `case class A1(x1: Int, y: String)`. So I have to convert that query to `{ "and" : {x1 = 0, y = "1"} }`.

I don't want to write such query converters manually every time I change `case class A` to `case class A1`. I want to write some "mapping" between `A` and `A1` (not sure how to do it) and then "derive" the query converter in *compile time*.  How would you suggest do that ? Should I use macros or a library for type-level programming ?

Comment: I would take a look to compile time frameworks like https://getquill.io/. There may be other possibilities. Maybe you can try to build your own converter at compile time using shapeless

Comment: Scala 2 macros or Scala 3 macros? In what format you work with JSONs? Circe? Play JSON? Something else?

Comment: We use Scala 2 and don't use macros. We use Jackson java library to parse JSON but I don't think it is related to the question.

Comment: It is relevant. Circe for instance let you work with JSON AST directly. It makes it relatively easy to define something like `trait FilterFromJSON[A] { def make(json: JSON): A => Boolean }` and derive the value of `FilterFromJSON[A]` using macros/Shapeless/Magnolia. Since Jackson uses runtime reflection it is at odds with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ! I will use Circe if it helps to derive this trait. Do I understand correctly that you suggest deriving type class instances of  `FilterFromJSON[A]` from `A` ?